# How to convert ARP code of JAVA to Kotlin in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arp

I am trying to get all the mac and IP from my android using the following code. But the following code only works in java. I want to use it in kotlin so I tried java to kotlin converter. But it didn't work. could anyone tell me how the following part of the code will be used in kotlin:

```
listNote.clear();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
            if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4) {
                String ip = splitted[0];
                String mac = splitted[3];
                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    Node thisNode = new Node(ip, mac);
                    listNote.add(thisNode);
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Auto conversion does not handle your while loop since "Assignments are not expression".

You can work around it by using built-in Readers extension function `forEachLine`, in which case each line is passed as the only argument to the lambda expression as `it`:

```
var bufferedReader: BufferedReader? = null
try {
    bufferedReader = BufferedReader(FileReader("/proc/net/arp"))
    bufferedReader.forEachLine {
        val splitted = it.split(" +".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
        if (splitted.size >= 4) {
            val ip = splitted[0]
            val mac = splitted[3]
            if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..".toRegex())) {
                listNote.add(Node(ip, mac))
            }
        }
    }
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
} finally {
    try {
        bufferedReader?.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

You can also remove `FileNotFoundException` since it's a subclass of `IOException`, and catch block is the same.